# Linking a jpeglib to in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

Hi I am trying to use `jpeglib` in my code and i have trouble linking it with my `Makefile`
I downloaded it in tar.gz file then extracted it and did all the `./configure` then the makes and all this stuff but now I have to link it in `Makefile` and I dunno how here is the `Makefile`

```
CFLAGS+= -Wall -Werror -fPIE -std=gnu99 -g
LDFLAGS=  -pthread 

HW=prgsem
BINARIES=prgsem

#LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib -ljpeglib
#CXXFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include
CFLAGS+=$(shell sdl2-config --cflags)
LDFLAGS+=$(shell sdl2-config --libs) -lSDL2_image



all: ${BINARIES}

OBJS=${patsubst %.c,%.o,${wildcard *.c}}

prgsem: ${OBJS}
    ${CC} ${OBJS} ${CXXFLAGS}  ${LDFLAGS} -o $@

${OBJS}: %.o: %.c
    ${CC} -c ${CFLAGS}  $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f ${BINARIES} ${OBJS}
```

The commented stuff is what I tried and didnt work. Also I tried to change the `#include` itself. Tried `#include "jpeglib.h"` also `#include <jpeglib.h>` nothing worked.

EDIT: added make compile error message

```
cc xwin_sdl.o event_queue.o prg_io_nonblock.o gui.o main.o prgsem.o messages.o keyboard.o computation.o utils.o   -pthread  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o prgsem
/usr/bin/ld: gui.o: in function `save_img':
/home/peter/Cprog/bab36prga-sem/gui.c:67: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/peter/Cprog/bab36prga-sem/gui.c:69: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/peter/Cprog/bab36prga-sem/gui.c:74: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/peter/Cprog/bab36prga-sem/gui.c:81: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/peter/Cprog/bab36prga-sem/gui.c:83: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/peter/Cprog/bab36prga-sem/gui.c:90: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/peter/Cprog/bab36prga-sem/gui.c:93: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/peter/Cprog/bab36prga-sem/gui.c:97: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:19: prgsem] Error 1
```

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: You should post the output of the command that "didn't work".

Comment: Your rules and recipes 
look super weird. Have a look on the built-in rules and implicit variables, then think real hard about whether you should do something different: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Comment: The makefile was supplied to me I should not Change The structure...I just need to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not during the *compilation* phase of your program, so changing the `#include` etc. won't help in this case.

Your problem is during the *linking* phase, so that means you have not added the library to your link line.  If, for example, the library is named `libjpeg.a` or `libjpeg.so`, then you need to add `-ljpeg` to your link line.  The easiest way is to add it to the end of `LDFLAGS`:

```
LDFLAGS+=$(shell sdl2-config --libs) -lSDL2_image -ljpeg
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I am so dumb actually should have tried this. :)

Comment: If the answer is what you need please accept it it so others know that the question has been answered.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am quite new to this page. Will do. Thanks.